# Quality of taking screenshot from a layout is different on smartphones

Tags: android, screen, screenshot

I take a screenshot from a Relative Layout that is includes ImageView and EditTexts but quality of output image is different on smartphones!
for example an output of *HTC Desire 310* with Android 4.2 is lower than *HTC ONE* with Android 6.

Low quality is obvious especially on Texts.
Quality of android screenshot by hardware buttons in HTC Desire is good but by the code is low.

This is my code

```
screen.setDrawingCacheQuality(ImageView.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bmScreen = screen.getDrawingCache();
File saved_image_file = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/test1.png");

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(saved_image_file);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return saved_image_file.getAbsolutePath();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you want quality output, you might wish to revisit your `compress()` call, and change the `0` to `100`.

Comment: on png,  quality percent will be rejected! zero or 100 is not important

Comment: Good point -- my apologies.

Comment: Using `getDrawingCache()` loses quality and some effects, like shadows. I faced that problem also and solved it using `uiautomator` (that was in tests). I don't know how to do the same in normal application, but I hope, I gave you some thoughts.